# How to copy image from DB to new path

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to copy an image using the path which is stored in my DB. I tried this but it throws "Array To String Conversion" error. I've never dealt with this before. Here's my code.

```
$record = AboutPageIntro::find($id);
$img_name = $record->image;
$ext = explode('.', $img_name);

Storage::disk('local')->copy(public_path($record->image), public_path('uploads/about_page/intro/' . uniqid() . '.' . $ext));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to convert an array from `explode('.', $img_name);` to a string in the final line.

```
$record = AboutPageIntro::find($id);
$img_name = $record->image;
$ext = explode('.', $img_name); // This is an array like ['image_name', 'ext]

Storage::disk('local')->copy(
    public_path($record->image), 
    public_path('uploads/about_page/intro/' . uniqid() . '.' . $ext[count($ext)-1])
); // You'll need to address the last item in the array by its index like this
```

That said, [`pathinfo(...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) is the safer option here.

```
$record = AboutPageIntro::find($id);
$img_name = $record->image;
$ext = pathinfo($img_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Storage::disk('local')->copy(
    public_path($record->image), 
    public_path('uploads/about_page/intro/' . uniqid() . '.' . $ext
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its a simple problem of using explode as it will return an array of strings based on the dividing parameter.

I'm not too savvy with OOP but I can suggest using str_replace or trim to remove the '.'s in the $img_name variable.

```
$record = AboutPageIntro::find($id);
$img_name = $record->image;
$ext = str_replace('.',"",$img_name);

Storage::disk('local')->copy(public_path($record->image), public_path('uploads/about_page/intro/' . uniqid() . '.' . $ext));
```